# Moles appears to require moled methods to be hashed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, moles

I am trying out Moles on a home project to (hopefully) be able to recommend that it be adopted in projects at work.  I am working with VS 10.0.30319 and Moles 1.0.0.0.

I have created the following class:

```
public class DeveloperTestControlBL
{
    public static bool VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatus(int tpid, int testStatusID) 
    {
        return false;   // For this example, always return false, 
                    // so that a return of true means the delegation worked
    }
}
```

In my test class, I have created a test which tests a class which calls the VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatus method.  I would have expected to have a declaration of the form:

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void TestPreTCIToEditReady_WithMoles()
{
   var devTCBL = new SDeveloperTestControlBL();
   devTCBL.VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatus = delegate(int tpid, int testStatusID) 
       {
            return true;
       }

// rest of the test here
}
```

What I have found is that to set the delegate I have to do this:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTest
    {

    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("Moles")]
    public void TestPreTCIToEditReady_WithMoles()
    {

   DelegateExample.Moles.MDeveloperTestControlBL.VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatusInt32Int32 =
       VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatusAlwaysTrue;


       // Rest of the test here
    }

    private bool VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatusAlwaysTrue(int tpid, int status)         
    {
       return true;
    }
```

Does anyone have any advice as to what I am doing incorrectly?  I have the
using Microsoft.Moles.Framework; statement and have a reference to DeveloperTestControlBL.Moles in the test project.

Thanks in advance,
Ron L

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   devTCBL.VerifyCurrentDevelopmentStatus (delegate(int tpid, int testStatusID) 
       {
            return true;
       });
```

It worked for me.